# How can I set the height of an element relative to its grandparent element?

Tags: html, css

```
<body> 
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

how can I set the "child" height relative to the body, while keeping the "parent" take the full height of the child?

Comment: Why are you trying to accomplish this? If you provide the reason, we might be able to provide an alternative solution.

Comment: I want to use the nth-child method, so I need a parent div

Comment: I want to set the height of the child to 50% of the body. I also want to use the nth child so I can alternate the design in my child div

Comment: You really can't do what you're asking without some other constraints. Will the body always be the height of the viewport? Will the parent element have a fixed or proportionate height?

Comment: I have set the body to be 100% height. I want the parent element has the same height as the total of the height of the div, and I want to add some more child so the height of the body cant be set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `body` is 100% of the viewport height, it's also 100 vh (viewport height) units high. You can use those to set your child elements:

```
body {
    height: 100%; /* could also be "100vh" for better clarity */
}
.child {
    height: 50vh; /* 50% of the height of the body and viewport
}
```

The parent element will then take the total height of the children, typically. You might have to fiddle with the `overflow` property on one or both, depending on their contents.